# How to run command from jenkins slave with administrator privileges

Tags: python, windows, jenkins

I tried to run python testcases using coverage.exe from **jenkins**, But I am getting some error like

`IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:`

The following command I am executing from jenkins

```
C:\JenkinsSlave\workspace\Python-2.7.14\python.exe -m coverage run -p TestAll.py
```

But when I am tried with command prompt as **"run as administrator"** then the same command working fine without throwing any permission error in testcases.

And I am using **Windows server 2008 r2**

Can anyone help me to execute the command from **jenkins** with administrator privileges.

Thanks